# sqrt() function not working in c what is my math error?

Tags: c

my sqrt() function is not working i a compiling from the command line and appending -lm

```
/** initialize distance formula **/
double formula1 = (x2-x1) * 2 * 2; 
double formula2 = (y2-y1) * 2 * 2;
double formula = formula1 + formula2;
/** call sqrt function to square root it **/
sqrt(formula);
printf("\n%lf", sqrt(formula));

return sqrt(formula);
```

my output answer is this -nanSTUDENTID@gio:~$

EDITTT HERE IS MY COMPLETE CODE BELOW, I apologize.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/** call math.h libbrary cause of sqrt() **/
#include <math.h>

/** define/declare constant **/
#define PI 3.14159

/** declaring prototypes **/
double distance(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2);
double radius(double point1, double point2, double point3, double point4);
double circumference(double circle_circum);
double area(double circle_area);

/** declare pointer **/
void getXY(double *xPtr, double *yPtr);

int main (void) {
    /** neither variables are initialized **/
    double x;
    double y;
    /** variables are now initialized **/
    getXY(&x, &y);

}

/** this function will prompt the user to enter x and y coordinates twice and then pass by reference to distance **/
void getXY(double *xPtr, double *yPtr) {
    /** neither variables are initialized **/
    double a;
    double b;
    /** variables are now initialized **/
    *xPtr = a;
    *yPtr = b;

    printf("First, lets get the center of a circle. \nPlease enter the x and y coordinates, separated by a space: \n" );
    scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b);

    /** neither variables are initialized **/
    double c;
    double d;
    /** variables are now initialized **/
    *xPtr = c;
    *yPtr = d;

    printf("Next, lets get a point on the circle \nPlease enter the x and y coordinates, separated by a space: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &c, &d);

    /** call distance function **/
    distance(a,b,c,d);
}
/** this function is gonna find this distance between two points **/
double distance(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {

    /** initialize distance formula **/
    double formula1 = (x2-x1) * 2 * 2; 
    double formula2 = (y2-y1) * 2 * 2;
    double formula = formula1 + formula2;
    /** call sqrt function to square root it **/
    sqrt(formula);
    printf("\n%lf", sqrt(formula));

    return sqrt(formula);
}
```

and I am passing lets say 1 0 & 0 0

Comment: Did you check `formula` is not a negative number?

Comment: What values are you passing in? The distance formula looks a bit odd.

Comment: Also, which `sqrt(formula)` is it failing on? What I mean to say is, assign that to a value and stop recalculating it unnecessarily.

Comment: be sure that formula1 + formula2 > 0

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I added my complete code

Comment: hint: `formula1 = pow(x2-x1,2.0)`, same goes for `formula2`.

Comment: Please, the formula you are using is badly coded, you are using `(x2 - x1) * 2 * 2;` what is `(x2 - x1)*4` and you need `(x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1)` (or `(x2 - x1)` to the power of two).  Also, you have to `#include <math.h>` or to use a proper prototype to `double sqrt(const double x);` so the compiler knows it's treating with a function returning a double.

Comment: Not really important, but the `l` modifier in the `printf` has no effect in standard C if the type is floating point i.e. `%lf` is the same as `%f`

Comment: pow(x2-x1, 2.0); calculates the power using logarithms, which is far less efficient than multiply something by itself.  Try to do (x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) for second power (or implement fast power algorithm for integer powers of numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does not raise `(x2 - x1)` to the second power; rather, it multiplies by four:

```
double formula1 = (x2-x1) * 2 * 2;
```

The same goes for the next line.

Once you've fixed those, things will improve (you will no longer be trying to compute the real square root of a negative number, which is what gives you the [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)).

Edit: To compute the square use either `(x2-x1) * (x2-x1)` or `pow(x2-x1, 2.0)`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It's correct, but it doesn't answer it.

Comment: @CompileError use pow()

Answer (score 1):

you'll be calling your distance function as

```
distance (x1=1, x2=0, y1=0, y2=0)
```

and then

```
double formula1 = (x2-x1) * 2 * 2;
```

will evaluate to -4

and then

```
 double formula = formula1 + formula2;
```

will evaluate to -4

thus

```
sqrt(formula);
```

as -nan